# I'm getting an infinite true bool error when I try to compile this C code and I don't know why

Tags: c, if-statement, boolean, cs50, inequality

This is the code

```
int numberofletters(string input)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0, n = strlen(input); i < n; i++)
    {
        if (65 <= (int) input[i] <= 90 | 97 <= (int) input[i] <= 122)
        {
            count += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            count += 0;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

and here is the error message when I try to compile

```
~/pset2/readability/ $ make readability
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    readability.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o readability
readability.c:19:34: error: result of comparison of constant 90 with boolean expression is always true [-Werror,-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare]
        if (65 <= (int) input[i] <= 90 | 97 <= (int) input[i] <= 122)
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~
readability.c:19:63: error: result of comparison of constant 122 with boolean expression is always true [-Werror,-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare]
        if (65 <= (int) input[i] <= 90 | 97 <= (int) input[i] <= 122)
                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~
2 errors generated.
```

I don't understand why this would create an infinite true statement, I'm creating two separate bounded spaces and saying if the strings ascii exists between either one then do something else do something else... Am I missing something?

Comment: Logical expressions cannot be chained like that in C, the logical OR is `||` not `|` and finally, use char literal instead of magic numbers.  `if (('A' <= input[i] && input[i] <= 'Z') || ('a' <= input[i] && input[i] <= 'z')`.

Comment: regarding: `int numberofletters(string input)`  How is `string` defined?  Note: `string` is not a valid type in C.  However, the `cs50.h` header file defines `string` as a macro that evaluates to `char *`.  Are you including `cs50.h` in your program?

Comment: regarding: `if (65 <= (int) input[i] <= 90 | 97 <= (int) input[i] <= 122)`  This is very confusing and assumes is using the ASCII character set.  Much better to have `#include <ctype.h>` and then the statement becomes: `if( isalpha( input[i] ) )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems.

The first is that the expression `65 <= (int) input[i] <= 90` is really `(65 <= (int) input[i]) <= 90`. That means you compare the boolean result of `65 <= (int) input[i]` with the integer `90`.

And, since the integral result of a comparison will always be `0` (false) or `1` (true), the chances of it being greater than `90` are, well, non-existent. *That's* why it's stating it "is always true".

The second is less of a problem, but you use the *bitwise* OR operator `|` instead of the *logical* OR operator `||`.

Finally, if you want to check if a character is a letter, use [`isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) instead. This correctly handles non-Latin-based alphabets as well.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't doing what you think it's doing:

```
65 <= (int) input[i] <= 90
```

This expression does not test if `input[i]` is between 65 and 90.  It actually parses to this:

```
(65 <= (int) input[i]) <= 90
```

So it first checks if `input[i]` is greater to or equal than 65.  That will result in a value of either 0 or 1.  So now you have either this:

```
1 <= 90
```

Or this:

```
0 <= 90
```

Both of which are true, which is why you're getting that warning.

You need to perform each check separately:

```
 if ((65 <= input[i] && input[i] <= 90) || (97 <= input[i] && input[i] <= 122))
```

Better still, get rid of the magic numbers and use character constants:

```
 if (('A' <= input[i] && input[i] <= 'Z') || ('a' <= input[i] && input[i] <= 'z'))
```

Or even better:

```
if (isalpha(input[i]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
65 <= (int) input[i] <= 90
```

C doesn't work like this.  You need to write:

```
65 <= (int)input[i] && (int)input[i] <= 90
```